# Cut date with Find command for select a date

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to cut from a similar result just the date, for example:

find dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/joseluis.com/ASDFookiwnloadRQ/ -name "$date*"

Result->

```
 /dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/joseluis.com/ASDFookiwnloadRQ/2018-07-30_TRANSACTION_123456789.jluis
```

I need to get `2018-07-30`.

I tried using `find` + `cut` but it is not possible because the file structure varies.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use cut here? Cut doesn't take a regex so it doesn't feel like the right tool here. I think this might be better off with grep:

Assuming the date value is always YYYY-MM-DD, you could do:

```
$ find . | grep -P '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}'  -o
2015-01-30
2016-11-10
2016-10-18
2016-12-06
2017-03-15
2017-03-03
2018-07-30
```

and that will get every value that matches the YYYY-MM-DD value from the regex.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions. Close them and move on.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can get just the string after the last slash

with `cut` the first 10 char of the string

```
echo "/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/joseluis.com/ASDFookiwnloadRQ/2018-07-30_TRANSACTION_123456789.jluis" | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | cut -c 1-10
```

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions. Close them and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Extra approach:

```
find dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/joseluis.com/ASDFookiwnloadRQ/ -name "$date*" | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -f1 -d_
```

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions. Close them and move on.